# how can i get record out by using date between certain columns

Tags: php, mysql

how can i get record out by using date between certain columns

Example.

I have a date value, 14-11-2013. I want the record in my tabel that has this value between startdate and end_date. I have tried with between statement and bigger/less then, but without sucess. Is this even possible?

This is my tabel: **time_periode** .. when i select *

```
id  start_time  start_date  end_time    end_date    payment_t.  payment_d   file_ready_d file_ready_t
11  1385337600  25-11-2013  1386460800  08-12-2013  1387238400  17-12-2013  1386892800  13-12-2013
10  1384128000  11-11-2013  1385251200  24-11-2013  1386028800  03-12-2013  1385683200  29-11-2013
9   1382918400  28-10-2013  1384041600  10-11-2013  1384819200  19-11-2013  1384473600  15-11-2013
8   1381708800  14-10-2013  1382832000  27-10-2013  1383609600  05-11-2013  1383264000  01-11-2013
```

Desired output

```
 id  start_time  start_date  end_time    end_date    payment_t.  payment_d   file_ready_d file_ready_t
10  1384128000  11-11-2013  1385251200  24-11-2013  1386028800  03-12-2013  1385683200  29-11-2013
```

Comment: Dates should stored using a date data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is `$time_period`, then use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE $time_period BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Alternatively, you can use double-comparison:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  t 
WHERE 
  $time_period>start_date 
  AND 
  end_date>$time_period
```

However, you should use proper format for your date as it's described in MySQL [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html) manual page. If that's not impossible, then there is [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  t 
WHERE 
  STR_TO_DATE($time_period, '%d-%m-%Y') 
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y') 
    AND 
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(end_date, '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: I will accept in 8 min..thank you for your correct answear :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE '2013-11-14' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Note the yyyy-mm-dd format of the date. This is mysql's native date format, and is what lets this query work. It would appear your `start_date` and `end_date` fields are probably just varchars, in which case this query will fail, because `08-12-2013` is not a valid mysql date. You should always store dates/times in native date/time formats and fields.